# CXF wsdl2java resulting in BINDING_MISSING_TYPE

Tags: java, validation, wsdl, cxf

Using java 6, CXF 2.3.1 and Maven 2.

When running CXF wsdl2java tool via the Maven plugin, I am encountering
the following issue:

> wsdl2java -d
>   C:\devel\adpoint_callback\target\generated-sources\cxf -impl -validate -verbose file:/C:/devel/adpoint_callback/src/main/resources/wsdl/foobar.wsdl
>   wsdl2java - Apache CXF 2.3.1
>
> WSIBP Validator found <binding> is NOT
>   a SOAP binding [DEBUG]
>
> org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException:
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException:
>   BINDING_MISSING_TYPE
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:279)
>
> ... ~20 rows
>
> Caused by: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: BINDING_MISSING_TYPE
>           at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:306)
>           at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:181)

Using the following minimal WSDL file adapted from http://www.w3schools.com/WSDL/wsdl_binding.asp :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="notification"   
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/mynamespace" 
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsd="http://example.com/mynamespace/xsd" >

    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://example.com/mynamespace/xsd" 
            targetNamespace="http://example.com/mynamespace/xsd" >
            <xs:element name="RequestType" type="xsd:content"/>
            <xs:element name="ResponseType" type="xsd:content"/>

            <xs:complexType name="content">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="getTermRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="xsd:RequestType"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="getTermResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="xsd:ResponseType"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="glossaryTerms">
        <wsdl:operation name="getTerm">
            <wsdl:input message="getTermRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="getTermResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="binding" type="glossaryTerms">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="getTerm">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/getTerm" />
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="testService" >
        <wsdl:port name="testPort" binding="binding">
            <soap:address location="http://example.com/mynamespace"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The service/binding usage is exactly as used in the example within the WSDL 1.1 specification document http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl

The code generation will not work without the -validate flag either - The validation warnings just do not show up.

Question is - of course - why the <soap:binding> element is not accepted as a binding type for the binding element as it should.

---

**[ EDIT : Fix ]**

If I set the default namespace to the same value as my targetNamespace, the error disappears.
Somehow the CXF is able to handle the fact that I do not set the default namespace up until the moment it was supposed to handle the binding. At that point it throws out a misleading exception about missing binding type.

Therefore, fixing this is as easy as changing the attributes of the wsdl:definition tag
to define the default namespace:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="notification"   
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/mynamespace" 
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsd="http://example.com/mynamespace/xsd"
        xmlns="http://example.com/mynamespace" >
```

Comment: I also had a similar problem. But it was assosiated with the fact that I hadn't put _targetNamespace_ in the _wsdl:definitions_. The fix was just to put it there.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `targetNamespace="http://example.com/mynamespace"` and define your binding like that:

```
<wsdl:binding name="binding" type="glossaryTerms">
    ...
</wsdl:binding>
```

Then you have to refer to that binding in the `wsdl:service` section with the corresponding namespace. Specifically, it should be: `binding="<namespace>:<binding_name>"`. It means that you have to define the namespace identical to the targetNamespace. For example, the namespace *tns*:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="notification"   
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/mynamespace" 
    ...
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/mynamespace">
```

And then, when referring to it in the `wsdl:service` section:

```
<wsdl:service name="testService">
    <wsdl:port name="testPort" binding="tns:binding">
        <soap:address location="http://example.com/mynamespace"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```